# What Android View do mobile browsers use to browse Internet?

Tags: android, webview

What Android View do mobile browsers use to browse Internet?
It is not WebView, but then what is it?

I tried to find it in [source code of Firefox for Android](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/firefox-android), but I could not launch it.

PS
I want to play video from Internet, it is playing in all mobile browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera), but it is not playing in WebView. The possible reason is that WebView uses standard Android MediaPlayer "under the hood", while browsers use their own mediaplayers.

[edit]

My WebView settings:

```
webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
webView.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
webView.settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true
webView.scrollBarStyle = View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY
webView.settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
webView.settings.pluginState = WebSettings.PluginState.ON
webView.settings.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false
webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true;
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlData, "text/html","UTF-8", null)
```

My WebView code:

```
val htmlData = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="file:///android_asset/playerjs.js"></script>
    <div id="playerjs" class="playerjs"></div>

    <script>
    var playerjs = new Playerjs({
        id: "playerjs",
        file: "https://url_of_videostream",
        player: 1
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
"""

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlData, "text/html","UTF-8", null)
```

It plays most of videos, but for some urls there are errors in log:
MediaPlayer java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider

Comment: What rights have you given your WebView (webView.getSettings().set...)?

Comment: Kindly post the WebView code for better understanding.

Comment: I would expect most first-class browsers (e.g., Firefox) to have their own custom views.

Comment: @Cloverleaf 
added webView code

Comment: @dennisrufigill
added webView code

Comment: @CommonsWare
Yes, it seems that Firefox uses GeckoView: 
https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/mobile/android/geckoview/consumer/geckoview-quick-start.html
I did not try it, will try later.